# RecurssiveAction in java 7

Tags: java, multithreading

I am checking billions of records which contains bunch of urls. So I want to check every url whether.It is valid url. Then It show in my application while searching particular url. So running a jobs for checking urls recursively. Now I using RecurssiveAction for this. Is it correct way?. Please give me valuable suggession.

Please find below Code

```
      public class JobsRecurssiveAction extends RecursiveAction {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


private final String[] domainsList;
private final Integer low;
private final Integer high;

private static final int THRESHOLD = 5000;

public JobsRecurssiveAction(String[] domainsList, int low, int high) {
   super();
   this.domainsList = domainsList;
   this.low = low;
    this.high= high;
}
@Override
protected void compute() {
    if (high - low < THRESHOLD) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = null;
          for (int i = low; i < high; ++i){
           mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            DomainList domainList = null;
         try {
             domainList =   mapper.readValue(cassandraService.getRedisValue(domainsList[i]), DomainList.class);
             cassandraService.deleteKey(domainsList[i]);
             int totalResources = domainList.getResourceCount();
             int totalCheckedResources = domainList.getTotalChecked();
             if(totalResources == totalCheckedResources){
                 cassandraService.resetDomainList(domainList);
             }
             cassandraService.stautsCheckerUrl(domainList);
             logger.info("domainList Domain :{} :: resourceCount:{}",domainList.getDomainName(),domainList.getResourceCount());
        } catch (Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
       }
    } else {
       int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
       invokeAll(new JobsRecurssiveAction(domainsList, low, mid), new JobsRecurssiveAction(domainsList, mid, high));
  }
}


}
```

Comment: Without more information I can't say how to help. A little code could help.

Comment: invokeAll() submits new requests to the framework. What you need to do is segment the current request with a fork(). Follow the examples in the javadoc for ForkJoinPool. Such as split left, right. left.fork() right.join().

Comment: I am adding these lines in compute method. Is it correect ?   Integer middile = (low + high) >>> 1;
JobsRecurssiveAction left = new JobsRecurssiveAction(domainsList, low, middile, resourceCassandraService);
JobsRecurssiveAction right = new JobsRecurssiveAction(domainsList, middile, high, resourceCassandraService);
           invokeAll(left, right);

Comment: Yes. Now do left.fork(); right.compute(); left.join(); Just follow the examples.

Comment: Thank you so much ... No need to add invokeAll(left,right)???

Comment: Thanks a lot... Now it works much better than earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  Fork/Join Framework which will help you in recursive approach. Its designed for tasks which can be broken into multiple tasks recursively.

Check:-

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html